# How to disable clear functionality of Java List

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `static` List property (e.g. `ArrayList<String>`) which is passed among multiple methods to add/modify elements. There are already few methods and in near future many methods to come.

So I need to ensure that no method could clear the list. So far I have overridden `clear()` method with empty method body.

My approach is as bellow:

```
private static List<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>(){
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        //here I disabled clear() with empty method 
    };
};

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    addNumber(singleList);
    addDigit(singleList);
    addSign(singleList);
    System.out.println(singleList);
}


private static void addNumber(List<String> singleList) {
    singleList.add("1");
    singleList.add("2");
}

private static void addDigit(List<String> singleList) {
    singleList.add("A");
    singleList.add("B");
    singleList.clear();// Suppose, this line wrote accidentally, and I need to prevent it.
}

private static void addSign(List<String> singleList) {
    singleList.add("+");
    singleList.add("/");
}
```

Is there any better option to do that?

Please suggest me.

Comment: What about using immutable list ?

Comment: Why do you need to disable clear but none of the other methods?

Comment: If you concerned about clear() why don't you care about remove()?

Comment: @YaroslavRudykh very good point ... thanks!

Comment: @rev_dihazum also, what about `singleList.subList(0, singleList.size()).clear()`?

Comment: @YaroslavRudykh don't forget `retainAll` too.

Comment: Note that "do nothing" violates the contract of [`Collection.clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#clear--): "The collection will be empty after this method returns." The method should throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose, you could use immutability. 
Instead of mutating the list, just return always an immutable one with the elements you want to have. You could use, for example, [Guava ImmutableList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html), create a builder and add the previous list and/or new elements.

[Guava docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html#clear()) about the `clear` method:

> Guaranteed to throw an exception and leave the collection unmodified.

Comment: This means changing all the other code which uses it in which case you would just replace `clear()` with setting an `emptyList()`

Comment: @PeterLawrey if clear is to be used, then yes. But the OP says that the methods should add elements, which in this case should either return the same immutable list, either another one.

Comment: So far I've not used Immutable List but I guess it will returns new object every time any modification occured. In mycase add/mod is allowed; just to make sure no method can clear the list.

Comment: @rev_dihazum in which case I would suggest your throw an exception to remove `clear()` from the code if it shouldn't be called.

Comment: The Guava Immutable List throws an exception on any attempt to modify the list; see my updated answer.

Comment: @loan thanks your suggestion; I UPVOTED you. But agree more with PeterLawrey's to avoid any third party library.

Comment: @rev_dihazum Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would add an `UnsupportedOperationException` to make sure the code which does call `clear()` is corrected.

If the code relies on `clear()` working, it shouldn't be using that collection.

If the code doesn't need `clear()` it shouldn't be calling it.

Comment: Thanks , So far your answer is the best fit for my requirement So I'm accepting it as answer.

Comment: Sorry, I have unaccepted it as answer(definitely given a UPVOTE) because there are lot of good concept are coming, so planning to decide few later. DONT mind plz

Comment: @rev_dihazum no problem, I don't need the rep ;)

Comment: Thanks for "DONT MIND" :)

Answer (score 2):

A better approach than *extending* `ArrayList` - although more verbose - is to *compose* `ArrayList` with a class which prevents clearing.

Basically, create a class which implements `List`, and delegates all of its method calls to another `List` instance, other than `clear`:

```
final class CannotClearList<E> implements List<E> {
  private final List<E> delegate;

  CannotClearList(List<E> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  @Override public boolean add(E element) {
    return delegate.add(element);
  }

  @Override public E get(int i) {
    return delegate.get(i);
  }

  @Override public void clear() {
    // Cannot "do nothing": that violates the definition of the
    // Collection.clear() method.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

  // etc, for all other methods.
}
```

Aside from the advantage that you aren't now restricted to having an `ArrayList` that you cannot clear (you could reuse it e.g. for a `LinkedList`), the real advantage in doing this is that in order to prevent `clear()` from working, you also have to prevent lists returned by `List.subList` from having `clear()` called on them.

If you have prevented `clear()` by extending `ArrayList`, you would need to then create another class which prevents `clear()` on the sublist also. However, with `CannotClearList` above, you can simply wrap the sublist in another `CannotClearList`:

```
@Override public List<E> subList(int from, int to) {
  return new CannotClearList<>(delegate.subList(from, to));
}
```

---

Note that `clear()` is not the only way to clear a list. You can also:

- Repeatedly call `remove`;
- Get an `Iterator` or `ListIterator` and call `remove()` whilst iterating that;
- Calling `retainAll(Collection<?>)` with an empty collection (or a collection with no elements in common) as the argument.

You should consider carefully whether you also want to prevent these cases.

Comment: I'm wondering how ``singleList.subList(0, singleList.size()).clear();`` clears the list! please explain, why is not calling overriden clear()?

Comment: [Refer to the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)) - and try it! Basically, it doesn't invoke the `ArrayList`'s `clear()` method, it invokes the `removeRange(int, int)` method instead.

Comment: Your approach is quite good but when I have implemented it I need to override lot of methods. is there any easier way ?

Comment: Sure. You can override all of the relevant methods in `ArrayList`, and then test to ensure that you've not missed a case. And then cross your fingers and hope that the implementation of `ArrayList` doesn't change [in a way that breaks your implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class). Oh wait, you said "easier"? :) If you can use Guava, you can use [`ForwardingList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html), which provides skeleton implementations of all methods; then you just override the necessary ones.

Comment: Which method I have to override to avoid ``singleList.subList(0, singleList.size()).clear();`` Plz tell me, BCoz its absent in your solution

Comment: By which approach? Using the approach suggested above, it's already in the answer, where it says `@Override public List<E> subList(int from, int to) {`. If you're using the extends approach, well... see, that's where it gets harder.

Comment: I have overridden ``removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`` to avoid ``singleList.subList(0, singleList.size()).clear();`` as you told but still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108888/discussion-between-rev-dihazum-and-andy-turner).

Comment: I didn't say to override `removeRange`. Doing so only in `ArrayList` will confuse the implementation of `ArrayList.SubList` because that assumes that the call to `parent.removeRange` removes elements. Also, this now prevents some other removal operations other than `clear`. Please don't try to take half of the solution if you don't understand what's going on - there are all sorts of subtleties to inheritance, which is why composition should be favoured.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `UnClearableList` which extends `ArrayList` - then in `UnClearableList` simply override the `clear()` method and do nothing in it (or possibly throw an exception, depending on your design).

Then use the UnClearableList when you are in such "I want to allow add / remove but no clear of my lists" cases.

Your way of doing it is technically correct. Doing this with a special UnClearableList lets you reuse it in other classes. 
If this is just a school exercise then it is not really necessary.

Comment: I've already done the same things, just see my code; I have done it using anonymous class.

Comment: yeah just edited my answer to explain that doing it in an external class allows reusability in other classes. Your technique is also correct

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new type or overloading an existing one (as you did) is the usual approach. Furthermore the interface `List` explicitly allows disabling `clear` as it is an optional operation.

From the JavaDoc:

```
/**
 * Removes all of the elements from this list (optional operation).
 * The list will be empty after this call returns.
 *
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the <tt>clear</tt> operation
 *         is not supported by this list
 */
void clear();
```